# error while running "sanity init" command in a Next.js project, failed at "Resolving dependencies"

Tags: sanity

I tried to run `sanity init` in a Next.js project and got the following error:

Error message image:

[image]

Comment: What version of the Sanity CLI are you using (`sanity --version`)?

Comment: 2.29.5
It's the latest release

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `npm install` or `yarn install`.